# Python: merging two datasets via df.merge() is simply not working

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I simply want to merg two datasets.

Sample df1:

|  | ID | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 73 | Dan |
| 1 | 74 | Emily |
| 2 | 75 | Kenny |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 333333 | 333407 | Liz |

Sample df2:

|  | Intention | Product ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | buy | 1001 |
| 1 | sell | 1002 |
| 2 | buy | 1002 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 333333 | buy | 1011 |

I want the result to look like this:

|  | ID | Name | Intention | Product |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 73 | Dan | buy | 1001 |
| 1 | 74 | Emily | sell | 1002 |
| 2 | 75 | Kenny | buy | 1002 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 333333 | 333407 | Liz | buy | 1011 |

I always used to do it this way and it always worked:

```
df1.merge(df2, left_on=df1.index, right_on=df2.merge)
```

But now I am getting an error:
`ValueError: Unable to fill values because RangeIndex cannot contain NA`

These datasets have the same number of rows, so the indexes. Cannot understand what's wrong. What do you think?

Comment: The information posted in the question is not enough. Check: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Hrm... try `df1.merge(df2, left_index=True, right_on='merge')`  Can you produce a small sample data generating this error?

Comment: @RobertoT can you check one more time, please. Thank you!

Comment: @ScottBoston can you check one more time, please. Thank you!

Comment: Seems like you just want to pd.concat these dataframe matching indexes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try `pd.concat`

```py
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
```

Or with

```py
df = df1.merge(df2, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```